# Can someone identify these Ninjago face mosaic sets?

Tags: set-identification, instructions, ninjago

I have 2 built 6x16 sets that appear to be Ninjago portraits. Each built on a Light Bluish Gray 6x16 plate with 1x1 colored bricks on top.  I suspect they may be Toys R Us builds but i just can't find them.

Does anyone know the set name or # or link to instructions?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently it's from [a 2015 Toys R Us building event](https://www.flickr.com/photos/neoape/16927100591/), in which there were 5 different mask kids could choose to build. There does not appear to be an item number associated with these builds.

[image]

All 5 designs and 3 of the instructions can be seen in [these images](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/lego-ninjago-toys-exclusive-ninja-1732550090) (click for full-size).

[image] [image]

I also found [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoHbXZQYYEA) where all 5 are built and the booklet is flipped through.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fan built back panel to combine and prop them up all nice and proper like.

The pictures are detailed enough to suss out build instructions or a workable modification.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you reposted the pictures - I thought you wouldn't after deleted your original answer

Comment: @ Scott, Had to step into the editing room;)

Comment: Interestingly these don't use the original pieces, which were all 1x1 bricks

Comment: Hmm.. Not only is the prop stand fan built, but the Ninjago masks too?  Yes, very interesting.  Builder could have been working with whatever pieces that got the job done the fastest.  Very efficient mind that one.

Answer (score 1):

This was a giveaway at Toys'R'Us [March 2015](https://www.ohyesitsfree.com/free-lego-ninjago-mask/). The [image I have found](https://thumbs.worthpoint.com/zoom/images1/1/0415/07/lego-ninjago-mask-set-all-five-ninjas_1_a8604054661c4f65783ef63a9a9561d7.jpg) suggests me these masks don't have a have a set number. Here you can also see how instructions looks like. These are not your standard LEGO instructions you can find in sets or with other promos. The lack of set number and the appearance of the booklet with instructions suggest me you cannot get PDF instructions from LEGO Service for this set of bricks.

Keeping in mind this is just a bunch of 1 x 1 bricks on top of the plate, there shouldn't be much of an issue replicating the rest of the masks.